# Graph from file c++

Tags: c++, vector, graph

I'm a beginner with c++ 
I need to read a graph from a file, so I've created this code, but the problem is that I can't debug it, I'll be glad if you would help me; 
this is my code :
Graph.h
`

```
class Graph
{
private:
   int nbSommets;
  int nbAretes;
  std::vector <std::list<int> > adjList(int);

public :
    void lire_fichier(int a, int b);
    void afficher_graph();
    void setArete(int x, int y);
    int get_nbSommet(){ return nbSommets; }
    int get_nbAretes()  { return nbAretes; };

};

#endif // GRAPH_H`
```

Graph.cpp

```
      #include "graph.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>


using namespace std;

Graph() {};

void Graph::lire_fichier(int a, int b)
{
  ifstream myfile;
  myfile.open( "fichier.txt", std::ios::in );
  if ( myfile ) 
    {
        string ligne;
    while (getline( myfile, ligne ) )
        {
            // ignorer les lignes inutiles
           if (ligne.empty() || ligne[0] =='c') 
        {
         continue;
        }

        else if(ligne.empty() || ligne[0] =='p')
        {
          istringstream ss(ligne);    
           string x,y;   
           ss >> x >> y >> nbSommets >> nbAretes;
        }
          else 
        {
          istringstream ss(ligne);
          string x; 
          ss >> x >> a >> b;
          vector <list<int> > adjList(nbSommets);
           adjList[a].push_back(b);
           adjList[b].push_back(a);

        }
    }  
    }
}

void Graph::afficher_graph()
{

    vector<list<int> >::iterator i;
    int c=0;
    for (vector<list<int> >::iterator i=adjList.begin(); i !=adjList.end(); ++i){


        cout<<"noeuds connecté à "<<c <<" sont ";
        //cout<<*i;

        list<int> li = *i;
        for(list<int>::iterator iter = li.begin(); iter!= li.end(); ++iter){

            cout<<*iter<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
        c++;
    }


}


void Graph::setArete(int x, int y)
{

}
```

This is my input file

```
c FILE:  brock200_2.b
c
c Graph Generator
c
c By: Mark Brockington (brock@cs.ualberta.ca)
c and Joe Culberson (joe@cs.ualberta.ca)
c
c Graph Size:200, Clique Size: 12
c Seed:20, Edge Density:  0.50000
c Depth 1 Hiding
c
c Clique Elements are:
c 26 120 119 157 69 182 47 148 104 134 
c 54 144 
c
c Estimated Size of Uncompressed File:   0.1MB
c
p edge 7 14
e 3 1
e 3 2
e 4 2
e 5 1
e 5 4
e 6 3
e 6 4
e 6 5
e 7 1
e 7 2
e 7 5
e 8 1
e 8 3
e 8 6
```

i've to ignore all lines begin with C,
and then get the Node and Edge p edge 7 14 (7 is number of Nodes) & 14 is number of edge

e 3 1, means that there is an edge between Node 3 and 1 ( it's an undirected Graph, so that's means that e 3 1 = e 1 3)

thanks for your help !! :D

Comment: Can't debug it?  What does that mean?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, sorry for my english :p 
anyway, i can't debug this errors, i don't understand 
error: ‘((Graph*)this)->Graph::adjList’ does not have class type
error: variable ‘std::istringstream ss’ has initializer but incomplete type
error: expected unqualified-id before ‘)’ token 
would you plz help me !!

Comment: Please edit your question with a sample of the input file.

Comment: Here: `else if(ligne.empty() || ligne[0] =='p')` ligne can not be empty because you already checked for that so this `if()` will never succeed.

Comment: i edited :D hope that's clear right now

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your reading function, you've a couple of mistakes, that bring you out of bounds of the `adList` vector:

```
    else
    {                          // you start a new block 
        ...
        vector <list<int> > adjList(nbSommets);  // and !!! redefine this variable, inside the block hiding the class member !!!! 
        adjList[a].push_back(b);  
        adjList[b].push_back(a);
    }                          // when you leave the block, the local adjList is forgotten
                               // and the original remains untouched
```

To correct the situation,  you have to get rid of this vector redrefinition (commenting  this vector line out),  AND reinitialize adjList at the moment you define the new size.  For example:

```
        else if (ligne.empty() || ligne[0] == 'p')
        {
            ...
            adjList.clear();   // empty thr vector
            adjList.resize(nbSommets);   // resize as you read from the file 
        }
```

Finally, a last test showed that your input file contains wrong data.  The following line defines the number of "sommets" to be 7:

```
p edge 7 14
```

Consequently, with the corrected code above, the adjList will be resized to contain items from 0 to 6.  The following bloc of lines will then still cause an out of bounds:

```
e 7 1
...
e 8 6
```

So you have first to correct the file, for example `p edge 9 14` instead of 7.

Here the output with `afficher_graphe()`:

```
noeuds connecté à 0 sont
noeuds connecté à 1 sont 3 5 7 8
noeuds connecté à 2 sont 3 4 7
...
noeuds connecté à 8 sont 1 3 6
```

Once this work, I strongly advise that you foresee some error detection code, for example to print out some warning messages and ignoring the bad lines.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so to solve this problem, what do i have to do ?? if i understund what you said, do i have to make it global ?? but it's only in the function that i can stockpile the edges ?? i didn't see what i have to do ,thanks for your answer again :D

Comment: @ZakLH, I updated the answer to give the indications.  I hope it is clear now.  If not, let me know.  By the way, promise me not to make this variable global ! ;-)